# If $P(X|W,Z)=P(X|W), P(Y|W,Z)=P(Y|W)$, then $P((X,Y)|W,Z)=P((X,Y)|W)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am lost with the following question. Assume that $W$, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables defined on some probability space such that
\begin{align*}
P(X=x|W=w,Z=z)&=P(X=x|W=w)\\
P(Y=y|W=w,Z=z)&=P(Y=y|W=w).
\end{align*}
Is it true that $P((X,Y)=(x,y)|W=w,Z=z)=P((X,Y)=(x,y)|W=w)$? If it is true, how can I prove it? If it is not true, are there conditions for this to be true?

Comment: What does $P(X|W)$ stand for?

Comment: I think I am not clear. Let me edit the question.

Comment: If$W$ is a constant the what you are asking is the following: if $X$ is independent of $Z$ and $Y$ is independent of $Z$ are $X$ and $Y$ jointly independent of $Z$. This is not true. To make it true your hypothesis has to say something about joint distribution if $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, @KaviRamaMurthy. You are right, I did not think about this problem in that way. I am a little confused, what happens if W is not constant?